# Run a query on database on selecting a value

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have populated a drop down list with php.

It looks like this :-

```
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","clinic","myclinic","myclinic");
      // Check connection

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }


    $query="SELECT DISTINCT doctor FROM schedule";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    echo "<br><br>
    <table border='1'><tr>
    <td>&nbsp;Doctor's Name&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;<select name='doctor'>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['doctor'] . "'>" . $row['doctor'] ."</option>";

    }       

    echo "</select>";
```

Now I have a few more drop down lists on my page. 
I want to run a script when I select a doctor from the list 
For example On selecting a doctor a List Days should populate with days the doctor is available. Executing a query

```
           SELECT days from appointments WHERE doctor="One who was selected";
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hello Dear for that you have to use ajax 
just follow these steps

1) create code for select doctor dropdown.

2) onchange of these dropdown call one jquery function that consist of ajax script to get days from other php page.

3) at other page retrive doctor id from request and fetch days according to doc_id and generate days dropdown.

4) now when user changes dropdown ajax is called and you will get days dropdown place it in some div by innerHTML.

Comment: Could you point to where I can read code for passing variables to a php script and retrieving the data into a div

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through combination of ajax and php 
Assuming I have another dropdown for showing total no of days doctor available

```
<select id = "days"><option value="">Select</option></select>
```

Now add a change event on doctor dropdown

```
$("#doctor").change(function(){
   // make a ajax call and retrieve days and populate days drop down accordingly
   $.ajax({ url: url, success: function(data){
   $("#days).empty(); //clear existing options
   $(data).each(function(i,v){
    $(#doctor).append(new Option(v,v);
   }); });
});
```

Assuming data is an array that ajax returns

Comment: Hmmm i don't know Ajax. Maybe I'll have to spend some time on it.

Is there anyway to do this with just plain javascipt and php?
I am still a newbie

Comment: Okay I think I understand some of it now. Except the function(i,v) part. what are 'i' and 'v' here?

Comment: i is index, and v is value, for eg if data consists of array of form , data[0] = "DAY1"; data[1] = 'Day2'; then i = 0 and v = Day2

Comment: Please provide positive rating, If I was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use Ajax functionality in it ia a manner when you select 
   a value from your first drop down you should send this  value from using query string 
   to php page and by the response you should populate your next drop down.for this you
   you need association between your two tables

Comment: Associate the two drop down lists you mean?
Both values are from the from the same mysql table

Comment: ok then just pass value from first drop down and fetch required column value from it